# Write dates in Excel without time using pywin32

Tags: python, pywin32

Is it possible to write date values using pywin32 to Excel without the time? Even though the `datetime` object I create has no time nor UTC associated to it, when writing the value to Excel it still adds an hour component which is related to UTC. How can I solve this simple problem?

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Sheets['Sheet1']

# Writes '01/01/2019 03:00:00' instead of '01/01/2019'
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the date with no time of day, you can call [`datatime.date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) to get it. Unfortunately the value must be converted to a string because the `win32com.client` won't accept a [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object directly.

```
# Writes '1/1/2019'
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = str(datetime(2019, 1, 1).date())
```

**Update:**
You can workaround the cell having a text entry by assigning an Excel *`formula`* to the cell instead. Doing this will allow you to use the cell more easily in conjunction with other formulas and its other capabilities (such as sorting, charting, etc).

```
# Writes 1/1/2019
ws.Cells(1, 1).Formula = datetime(2019, 1, 1).strftime('=DATE(%Y,%m,%d)')
```